# Reload same View Controller but with different information

Tags: ios, swift, null, segue, viewcontroller

I have a Detail View Controller and I want to show the same Detail View Controller but with a different item.

```
var nexttype : Type!
let nexttypeVC = TypeDetailVC()


@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    nexttype = type.Array![0]
    nexttypeVC.type = next.type

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nexttypeVC, animated: true)


}
```

When I print the name or a identifier of the item I get the correct one, but when I launch the simulator I get error.  The values of the labels and everything is nil.

How can I tell the view controller to reload again but with a different item?

Comment: form where you are getting new data?

Comment: you can use a tableView with one cell and design your view there and just reload it for change.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Instead of pushing the same view controller onto the navigation stack. Try to arrange all the logic to update UI elements into a method. Call this method in `viewDidLoad()`. Calling `self.viewDidLoad()` is not a good idea.

Use observer pattern and call the method that updates UI elements.

Comment: Don't call `viewDidLoad`; create a function that sets up the UI elements based on the data and call that function from both `viewDidLoad` and when you load new data.

Comment: It is really bad practice to call viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

Call performSegue(withIdentifier:) rather than pushViewController.  You'll need to programmatically register a segue or add one via storyboard.  Then use prepare(for segue: sender:) to give the destination ViewController the item you wish.  Note that the destination's viewDidLoad() is called *after* the prepareForSegue.

This is the standard Apple-recommended way to seed the destination ViewController with data it needs prior to its load.